# Why does Rule behave like this?

Tags: evaluation, replacement

Why does

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]
```

result in

```
{x, f[2], f[3], a, b}
```

when `->` is supposed to be evaluated immediately? Shouldn't it produce something like

```
{x, f[n], f[n], a, b}
```

with `:>` (RuleDelayed) producing `{x, f[2], f[3], a, b}`? Note that `:>` also gives `{x, f[2], f[3], a, b}` (as expected).

Excuse the silly question, but I am rather baffled.

Comment: I think that's because `n` is on both sides  of `->`, so it's treated like a function. So for `x^2`, the rules says, make it a function, with 2 as its input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The use of `Rule` (`->`) *does* cause the right-hand-side to be evaluated but if a pattern Symbol (such as `n`) remains its left-hand-side match will still be substituted in.  Observe what happens when `f[n]` evaluates to different expressions.

No `n` present in evaluated form:

```
f[n] = 7;

{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]
```

> ```
> {x, 7, 7, a, b}
> ```

Note that only literal `f[n]` evaluates to `7`; `f[2]` or `f[3]` will remain unevaluated.

Multiple instances of `n` present in evaluated form:

```
f[z] = n^2 + Sin[n];

{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[z]
```

> ```
> {x, 4 + Sin[2], 9 + Sin[3], a, b}
> ```

Note again that this is *not* `f[n_] := . . .`.  First `f[z]` evaluates to `n^2 + Sin[n]` and then each appearance of `n` is replaced with the LHS match.

Note also that further evaluation of the RHS is not immediately performed after filling with LHS matches:

```
Hold[x, x^2, x^3, a, b] /. x^n_ -> f[z]
```

> ```
> Hold[x, 2^2 + Sin[2], 3^2 + Sin[3], a, b]
> ```

Here `2^2` and `3^2` remain unevaluated due to `Hold`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because n is on both sides of ->, so it's treated like a function. So for x^2, the rules says, make it a function, with 2 as its input.

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]
```

> {x, f[2], f[3], a, b}

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ :> f[n]
```

> {x, f[2], f[3], a, b}

Now we define the function `f[z_]`

```
f[z_] := Sqrt[z] // N

{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]
```

> {x, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], a, b}

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ :> f[n]
```

> {x, 1.41421, 1.73205, a, b}

[image]