# Implementation of a recursive function

Tags: recursion

I have been trying to implement a recursive function, but still struggle. Here's what I have written:

```
Subscript[p, n_] := Subscript[p, n - 1] + (n + 1)*x^n

Subscript[p, 1] = 1
```

And executing

```
Subscript[p, 4]
```

I get

> ```
> 1 + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 +5 x^4
> ```

Now, I tried to define:

```
Polynom[x_] := Subscript[p, 4]
```

However, when I try to evaluate

```
Polynom[4]
```

I still get the result:

> ```
> 1 + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 5 x^4
> ```

So *Mathematica* didn't replace `x`  with `2` . Can anyone explain to me why or how I can define the function I want so it evaluates for `Polynom[4]`?

Comment: Your definition of Polynom[x_] does not involve any variable x on the right-hand side, it merely assigns all values of Polynom to the single constant value Subscript[p,4].  You seem a novice with Mathematica notation, function definition, etc.

Comment: Related: [(8829)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/121), [(70030)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70030/121)

Comment: Please see the link below "This question already has an answer here:" at the top of your question as well as the "Related:" links directly above.  In this case you could simply define `Polynom[x_] = Subscript[p, 4];` but it is very important that you understand *why* this works and its limitations.  After reading those Q&A's please let me know if it remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, n_] := f[x, n - 1] + (n + 1)*x^n

f[x_, 1] = 1;

polynom[x_] := f[x, 4]

polynom@4  (*1585*)
```

---

If I understand your purpose correctly,

$$a_{m,n}=a_{m,n-1}+(n+1)m^n$$

I propose using `Nest` to implement this recursive formula.

$$\{a_{m,n-1},m,n-1\} \Rightarrow \{f(a_{m,n-1},m,n-1),m,n\}$$

where

$$f(x,y,z)=x+(z+2)y^{(z+1)}$$

```
a[m_,n_,val_]:=
 First@
    Nest[{#1 + (#3 + 2) #2^(#3 + 1), #2, #3 + 1} & @@ # &, {val, m, 1}, m-1]
```

where `val` is the value of $a_{m,1}$

```
 a[4, 1, 1]
 (*1585*)
```