# How to define a function that utilizes the Range function?

Tags: function-construction

How can I define a function that uses the Range function in its definition.
A very simple example would be

```
f[x_]=Range[x]
```

However if I try that it outputs
"Range specification in Range[x] does not have appropriate bounds"

A more complex use would be

```
f[x_]=Select[Range[x], OddQ[#] == True &]
```

Which should give all odd numbers below x.

However neither of these work due to the problem with Range. Is there any way I can fix this, or another function I can use that has the same effect?

Comment: Try `f[x_]:=Range[x]`

Comment: You'll want to use `:=` instead of `=`. More information is available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/731).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that and delete this question.

Comment: See also [(22917)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121) and [(70030)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70030/121) for related issues regarding replacement rules.